# So do C#4.0 Code Contracts Actually Do Anything?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, code-contracts

After reading about the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract` static class that has been influenced by the awesomeness of Spec# I was thrilled and immediately started peppering my code with calls to `Contract.Requires()` and `Contract.Ensures()`.

I guess it's just because my code is so super-awesome and bug-free that checking that those calls actually did something just didn't come up until recently.  A bug slipped through and I came to the realization that these calls do not do anything!  I would have thought that they at least throw an exception when the condition is violated but no such luck.

Am I missing something?  Does anyone know what the heck is the point?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [the Contract Class page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412891(v=VS.100).aspx):

> You must use a binary rewriter to
>   insert run-time enforcement of
>   contracts. Otherwise, contracts such
>   as the Contract.Ensures method can
>   only be tested statically and will not
>   throw exceptions during run time if a
>   contract is violated. You can download
>   the binary rewriter CCRewrite from
>   Code Contracts on the MSDN DevLabs Web
>   site. CCRewrite comes with a Visual
>   Studio add-in that enables you to
>   activate run-time contract enforcement
>   from the project Properties page. The
>   binary rewriter and the Visual Studio
>   add-in do not ship with Visual Studio
>   2010 or the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on JSBangs' answer:

You must check the "Perform Runtime Contract Checking" box here:

[image]

(I also checked the "Static Checking > Peform Static Contract Checking" box)

Comment: Also of note, the [code contracts visual studio extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/02de7066-b6ca-42b3-8b3c-2562c7fa024f) which will attempt to parse your contracts and inform you of issues before you even build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `.Requires` call to throw an error you need to set an option in project settings or use `.Requires<T>` call

Comment: What do you mean?  What option? I am using .Requrires()

Comment: Under project properties, head to the "Code Contracts" tab.